# Converting sys.argv to positional argparse argument?

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse, argv

I have a script that currently takes both `sys.argv` and `argparse` arguments. I need to change the `sys.argv` input into a positional `argparse` argument. How would I do this?

Script (irrelevant sections omitted):

```
import sys
import argparse
from pathlib import Path

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument("-ru", "--remove-unparsable", dest="remove_unparsable",
                    action="store_true",
                    help="When this option is enabled, unparsable fonts are "
                         "removed instead of ignored")

args, unknown = parser.parse_known_args()

def handle_path(path: Path):
    if path.stem.startswith("."):
        return
    if path.is_dir():
        for f in path.iterdir():
            handle_path(f)
    else:
        handle_file(path)

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        print(f"Usage: {sys.argv[0]} [<files>]")
    else:
        for path in sys.argv[1:]:
            if not path.startswith("-"):
                handle_path(Path(path))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Wait, what? The primary point of `argparse` is to parse `sys.argv`. Why are you trying to also handle `sys.argv` yourself?

Comment: `argparse` already takes input from `sys.argv` if you don't specify something else.

Comment: Fix it by using one or the other, not both.

Comment: ...so why are you looking at `sys.argv`, instead of looking at `unknown`? (Or, even better, telling argparse to put positional arguments into a variable inside `args`?)

Comment: This script previously used `sys.argv`, and I edited it to add an `argparse` argument. However, the original author of the script wants me to convert the `sys.argv` input to `argparse` in order for them to accept my pr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    
    parser.add_argument("-ru", "--remove-unparsable", dest="remove_unparsable",
                        action="store_true",
                        help="When this option is enabled, unparsable fonts are "
                        "removed instead of ignored")
    parser.add_argument("files", nargs="+")
    args, unknown = parser.parse_known_intermixed_args()
    for path in args.files:
        handle_path(Path(path))
```

Here, [`ArgumentParser.parse_known_intermixed_args`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_known_intermixed_args) handles the positional `files` argument, which can be intermixed with named arguments such as `-ru` and unknown arguments. The `nargs="+"` parameter specifies that at least one file must be present.